# How to fill highlighted boundary in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image in which certain area is highlighted by red colour as shown:[image]

I want to fill it with black colour. The code which I have used to highlight the area is:

```
image= read('image.jpg');
figure,imshow(image);
cropped=image(200:240,100:480,:);
thresh=200;
lw=im2bw(cropped,thresh/255);
lw=bwareaopen(lw,100);
[B,L]=bwboundaries(lw,'noholes');
numRegions=max(L(:));
stats=regionprops(L,'all');
shapes=[stats.Eccentricity];
g=[stats.MinorAxisLength]
q=[stats.MajorAxisLength]
u=[stats.Orientation]
keepers=find(abs(u)<12);
imshow(cropped)
for index=1:length(keepers)
    outline=B{keepers(index)};
    line(outline(:,2),outline(:,1),'color','r','LineWidth',2);
end
```

How can I use imfill command to fill it as I have only the outline of the highlighted area.